# How to call subprocess on network machine with its environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

Say I have the following `open_calc.py` script on a machine that's on the network:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['calc.exe'])
```

This simple script merely opens the Windows calculator and ends. Then, on a local machine, I have `invoke_network_calc.py` script that contains:

```
import imp
lecroyModule = imp.load_source('module', r'\\network_machine\c$\open_calc.py')
```

If I run `invoke_network_calc.py` from the local machine, the calulator opens on the **local** computer. My question is, is there a way to do this so that the calculator is open on the **network** computer? Or, more generally, is there somthing that can be done so that from that point on, when `subprocess.call` is called, it starts the process in a different environment? I know this can be done if I simply invoke the **network's** Python engine with `open_calc.py`, but is there a way to do this without starting a separate Python process?

**EDIT**: Perhaps a piece of wishful code will further specify what I'm looking for:

```
redirector = Redirector('network_machine')
redirector.start() # from here on, subprocesses are executed on the remote machine
lecroyModule = imp.load_source('module', r'\\network_machine\c$\open_calc.py') # calculator will be opened on remote computer
redirector.stop() # from here on, subprocesses are executed normally (on the local machine)
lecroyModule = imp.load_source('module', r'\\network_machine\c$\open_calc.py') # calculator will be opened on local computer
```

So basically, I'm asking if anyone knows of a way to implement the `Redirector` class.

Comment: Usually there is a service running on a remote machine e.g., ssh server that accepts requests from a client e.g., a Python script that runs on your local machine and submits commands via ssh using subprocess, or paramiko, or fabric modules. There could be a specific to Windows command that allows to run commands on a remote computer. Or you could use something like [`execnet`](http://codespeak.net/execnet/) where both server and client are written in Python.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for your comment. Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough. I'm looking for a way to "redirect" subprocesses to open on a remote machine. Since I may not know what these processes may be, I cannot simply invoke them remotely. I have added some "wishful code" to the question to add clarity.

Comment: In what way `execnet`  does not work for you? It can run python code (that runs processes that your "may not know") on a remote machine.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm looking for a way so that the output (stdout) of the script that is run on the remote machine will be displayed on the local machine. It seems that with `execnet`, the output will be displayed on the remote.

Comment: where do you want GUI applications to show their windows? Do you want these processes to accept input from the local keyboard/mouse?

Comment: I want all subprocesses to be opened on the remote machine (including GUI windows. These processes are not expected to accept any input from the local keyboard/mouse) but any python output (like that printed by the `print` statement) will be displayed on the local machine for monitoring reasons.

Comment: [the very first example shows how to send the output back](http://codespeak.net/execnet/example/test_info.html)

Comment: Yes, but that will require me to change the code on the remote machine, which is code I do not have access to.

Comment: no, it won't. If you don't know how to do it, ask

Comment: I read through the docs and tried a few examples myself, but did not succeed with what I'm trying to do. If you can assist with a small example, that would be very helpful. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried the first example I've linked above? Does it work (unmodified) exactly as described in the docs on your machine? 1. Learn how to redirect the output of a *local* Python script that might run other processes, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279). make sure that you can get the output of `open_calc.py` *locally* without modifying `open_calc.py`  itself 2. Run that code via execnet on the remote machine, use `channel.send()` to send the output back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72031/discussion-between-user2016436-and-j-f-sebastian).